# Handle Message Exceptions in Weboscket with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, error-handling

**ABOUT MY PROBLEM:**

I need to handle some exceptions in my ChatController. Below, you can see an example of what I'm referring to:

```
@MessageMapping("/message")
@SendTo("/chatroom/public")
public PublicMessageDTO receivePublicMessage(@Payload @Valid PublicMessageDTO message,
                                             Principal principal) {
    if (principal == null)
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

    return messageService.createPublicMessage(message, principal.getName());
}
```

With this piece of code, I'm blocking an invalid message before it can be saved in the repository. However, nothing is communicated to the client, and I need to add an event in ReactJS if the WebSocket returns an error.

What do I need to do to solve my problem?

**WHAT I HAVE BEEN TRYING TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:**

I also tried to add a method annotated with @MessageExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class) from the Spring Messaging library, but the only thing I have solved is that no unexpected error is thrown in the Java Console.